# In how many ways can 4 couples sit in a row if no 2 women sit next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The Numbers of ways?

I am so confussed- I have looked at it tones of different ways and its not working. 
The previous question was the same thing but using 7 couples and the answer was 203,212,800 and no matter what I tried I couldn't get that answer or the one for this version of the question.

Please help me understand the method of doing this type of problem?

Comment: Is the problem outdated enough to assume that "couple" means "one man, one woman"?

Comment: @ZevChonoles +1 very good question

Comment: Also, do both members of each couple have to be sitting next to each other?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a couple to be one man and one woman, each seat has two possibilities,
 man or woman. With 7 men and 7 women, and for there not to be any women sitting next to one another, each woman must be delimited by at least one man.

_ M _ M _ M _ M _ M _ M _ M _

There are 8 spaces that the 7 women can be placed into:

$$\frac{8!}{(8-7)!}=8!$$

In addition to that, there are 7 men that can be placed into $7!$ different permutations, so by the rule of product the final expression is:

$$8!\space 7!=203212800$$

Use the same process for 4 couples.